# How do I catch exceptions when a task triggered by gulp-watch fails?

Tags: javascript, less, gulp, gulp-watch

I use the following gulp task to transform less into css. I start it once and upon less-file changes it updates css.

```
gulp.task('watch-less', function () {

  gulp.watch('app/styles/*.less', function (event) {

    try {
      var filename = event.path;
      gulp.src(filename)
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(less())
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('app/styles/'));

    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  });
});
```

The problem: Sometimes, less fails and stops with an error message like

```
events.js:72
    throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
          ^
Error: Unrecognised input in file
```

Obviously my try catch mechanism is wrong, I think it protects the pipe-building step but not the pipe-running time.

**Q: How can I write the gulp-watch task, so it continues working when less fails?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either go with events

```
gulp.src(filename)
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(less())
    .on('error', console.log)
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('app/styles/'));
```

Or use `gulp-plumber`:

```
 var plumber = require('gulp-plumber')

 ...

 gulp.src(filename)
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(less())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('app/styles/'));
```

Comment: btw.: I'm not sure if putting that into the function of watch is a good idea. You should reconsider putting it into a task.